# How to read in a Jenkins Web Hook post request body?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have an application that is triggering a Jenkins job via a Web Hook.  The web hook makes a POST request that contains data I need to use within the Jenkins Job - different actions will be taken depending on the request body.

How do I pass this request body to my script? - Is is accessible from the Build Actions?

I haven't written the script yet, but it may be in Bash, or Python.

Is the Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) the way to go?

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the Generic [Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) the way to go?

Yes, considering it can extract from a response body in JSON any value you want, as illustrated [by this issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/31).

```
  genericTrigger {
   genericVariables {
    genericVariable {
     key("VARIABLE_FROM_POST")
     value("\$.something")
     expressionType("JSONPath") //Optional, defaults to JSONPath
     regexpFilter("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
     defaultValue("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
    }
   }
   ...
```

That would extract from the JSON response body the "something" element value.

And/or you can [get back the all JSON payload](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/50).

> If you specify the JSONPath as just `$` then that should evaluate to all json.